# WooCommerce product gallery get image markup

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am using this filter and I would like to r:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'foo_add_featured_in_single_product_thumbnail', 10, 2 );

function foo_add_featured_in_single_product_thumbnail($html, $thumbnail_id){


    return $html;
}
```

When I have multiple images set (in product gallery), in single product section, woocommerce creates this markup for every image:

```
<div data-thumb="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-100x100.jpg" data-thumb-alt="" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 600px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;"><a href="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2.jpg"><img width="600" height="600" src="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-600x600.jpg" class="wp-post-image" alt="" loading="lazy" title="beanie-2.jpg" data-caption="" data-src="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2.jpg" data-large_image="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2.jpg" data-large_image_width="801" data-large_image_height="801" srcset="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-600x600.jpg 600w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-100x100.jpg 100w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-80x80.jpg 80w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-768x768.jpg 768w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2.jpg 801w" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" draggable="false"></a><img role="presentation" alt="" src="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2.jpg" class="zoomImg" style="position: absolute; top: -200.733px; left: -69.1147px; opacity: 0; width: 801px; height: 801px; border: none; max-width: none; max-height: none;"></div>
```

My question is how can I get just a product image html?   (without <a href tag and img role="presentation" )

I could use

```
$html = woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail('woocommerce_single');
```

Which creates this markup:

```
<img width="600" height="600" src="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-600x600.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_single size-woocommerce_single" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-600x600.jpg 600w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-100x100.jpg 100w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-80x80.jpg 80w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2-768x768.jpg 768w, http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/beanie-2.jpg 801w" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" draggable="false">
```

However this will work only for first product image. How can I get similar markup for other product images (based on thumbnail_id I guess).

In the end I would like to remove lightbox feature (which I can do with remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' )) and create my own lightbox, but I need markup for every image in product gallery.

I would like to leave gallery slider feature (wc-product-gallery-slider).